# How do I skip printing null elements in an array during *ngFor in Angular?

Tags: angular, ngfor

I am struggling to exclude empty entries from a database while trying to output the contents of the array in Angular.

```
       <div class="container" *ngFor="let trees of (this.trees || [])"

          <li>  {{trees.title}} </li>
          <li>  {{trees.paragraph1}} </li>
          <li>  {{trees.paragraph2}} </li>
          <li>  {{trees.paragraph3}} </li>

</div>
```

So for example, if an entry had nothing populated for `paragraph2`, I would like it to be skipped. However, an empty space printing out the white space is just there instead.

I have tried using `*ngIf="trees != null"` within the container but it does not work.

Does anyone have any advice on this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `let trees` is a creation of local variable using inside `for-each loop`. Should be named as single. All looks like: `*ngFor = "let variable of collection"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the simplest and cleanest way to go about this would be to exclude the `null` values first - in your `component.ts` file, using `array.filter()`:

```
let arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', null];

let arr2 = arr1.filter(i => i !== null); // will be ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Then simply use your `*ngFor` to iterate over the clean array in your `component.html`.

Your implementation will be a little more complex than what you see above, but the principle is the same: clean the data in the component first, and let the view be an un-opinionated consumer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to skip all four li if paragraph2 is null, you can do it as below:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let tree of trees">
  <div class="container" *ngIf="tree.paragraph2">
    <li>{{tree.title}} </li>
    <li>{{tree.paragraph1}} </li>
    <li>{{tree.paragraph2}} </li>
    <li>{{tree.paragraph3}} </li>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you want something like this:

```
    <div class="container" *ngFor="let tree of (this.trees || [])">

    <li *ngIf="tree.title"> {{tree.title}} </li>
    <li *ngIf="tree.paragraph1"> {{tree.paragraph1}} </li>
    <li *ngIf="tree.paragraph2"> {{tree.paragraph2}} </li>
    <li *ngIf="tree.paragraph3"> {{tree.paragraph3}} </li>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let tree of trees">
  <div class="container" *ngIf="tree!=null">
    <li>{{tree.title}} </li>
    <li>{{tree.paragraph1}} </li>
    <li>{{tree.paragraph2}} </li>
    <li>{{tree.paragraph3}} </li>
  </div>
</ng-container>


also always use trackby while using ngFor so DOM doesn't gets rendered everytime.
```